# Django makemessages for apps in site-packages

Tags: django, localization, gettext, django-manage.py

How can I collect translation strings outside of my project folder using Django's built-in [`makemessages`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) facility? The management command `makemessages` is very convenient and I'd like to use it for applications located in site-packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than makemessages I found [PyBabel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) very useful. Here is a bind to Django itself: http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/BabelDjango

Answer (score 12):

(1) Activate a virtual environment where Django is installed.

(2) Go directory of the app for which you want the messages to be generated:

```
$ cd path/to/app/in/site/packages/
```

(3) Make sure it has "locale" directory. If not - make one.

```
$ mkdir locale
```

(4) From your app directory run the following command:

```
$ django-admin.py makemessages -l [LANGUAGE_CODE]
```

Example for Dutch:

```
$ django-admin.py makemessages -l nl
```

Example for Russian:

```
$ django-admin.py makemessages -l ru
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP asks, does this collect strings *outside* of the project? As far as I know, this will just collect strings from html, txt, and py files inside of the project or app.

Comment: Yes, it does collect strings from the package you are running it from. That's why we have ``cd path/to/app/in/site/packages/``.

Answer (score 0):

With symbol links (ln -s) but it's not very convenient. Usually if the apps are on PYTHONPATH shouldn't the translations folders be catched by makemessages ?

Comment: Now I *do* use symlinks but that's an ugly workaround. It's hard-coded in *makemessages.py* to find files in the current working directory, it skips PYTHONPATH.

Comment: When using symlinks remember to add the `--symlinks` option to [`makemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages)